# How to format annotations in one line in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

See below, the annotation @Override and method definition in the one line after format codes, how to let annotation on the top of the method in the one line??

```
private static void testThread() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("t1");
        }
    });
    t1.start();
}
```

Here is what I want after code format, how to do.

```
private static void testThread() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("t1");
        }
    });
    t1.start();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want here.  The `@Override` annotation rightfully belongs next to/on top of the `run()` method because you are overriding that method in `Runnable.`  Putting it anywhere else would not make sense, since this annotation exists partly as a reminder to the developer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want `@Override` in the exclusive line. see the lastest question.

Comment: Ah...so you're only complaining that IntelliJ is giving you weird formatting.  Follow the duplicate link for how you might handle this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks,that not works fine for me, but should wrap for method annations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell IntelliJ how to wrap (or not wrap) method annotations as follows:

- Browse to `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java`
- Then open the `Wrapping and Braces` tab and look for `Method Annotations` - Right click next to that and choose `Wrap always`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but should select `Wrap always`

Comment: Oops, typo. Updated now, thanks.